# make: *** No rule to make target `cookie.h', needed by `mainProg.o'. Stop. Your makefile does not build 'playChomp' when invoked:playChomp

Tags: unix

[Error i get!-----------------/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKLuZ.png)           
[This is what my makefile looks like/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/215Mz.png)

i am trying to Compile `cookie.cpp` to produce cookie.o.

Compile `mainProg.cpp` to produce `mainProg.o`.

Link the the `.o` files to produce an executable program named playChomp

`mainprog.cpp`' file has the header of `cookie.h`

i am working in unix in an ssh terminal linux server

```
makefile..  
**all: playChomp

playChomp: mainProg.o cookie.o cookie.h
        g++ -g -DDEBUG mainProg.o cookie.o -o playChomp

cookie.o:cookie.cpp
        g++ -g -DDEBUG -c cookie.cpp

mainProg.o: mainProg.cpp cookie.h
        g++ -g -DDEBUG -c mainProg.cpp**
```

Comment: Please copy and paste text; do not link as image.

Comment: it wont let me copy paste the image.

Comment: sorry i am new to this page. it says i need a reputation of 10 in order to not link anymore

Comment: @BryanPerez: Paste the *text itself*, not the image of the text.

Comment: Paste the text.  Not the image.  Does cookie.h exist in the same directory as mainprog.cpp?

Comment: howss that , sorry for the mess

Comment: @B-rad ok.  you can format code by clicking the curly braces icon in the question editor or indenting 5 or more spaces.  **But regardless**, does cookie.h exist in the same directory as mainprog.cpp?

Comment: @Eric yes cookie.h exist in the same directory as mainprog.cpp

Comment: @B-rad then the error is rather mysterious.  See my answer below to double check everything and see if you discover the issue based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post some basic information that helps the people to understand better your problem. A few suggestions:

1. Try making a more meaningful title, put the error message that you receive into the title.
2. Put the source code of your program into your post. If possible, try to reduce it to a minimum content that still generates the same error message.
3. Inform your Operational System, Language that you are working on, what version, etc.

Comment: appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following directory listing:

```
$ ls
cookie.cpp  cookie.h  mainProg.cpp  Makefile
```

Then the Makefile you have provided:

```
all: playChomp

playChomp: mainProg.o cookie.o cookie.h
    g++ -g -DDEBUG mainProg.o cookie.o -o playChomp

cookie.o: cookie.cpp
    g++ -g -DDEBUG -c cookie.cpp

mainProg.o: mainProg.cpp cookie.h
    g++ -g -DDEBUG -c mainProg.cpp
```

Will produce the desired executable:

```
$ make all
g++ -g -DDEBUG -c mainProg.cpp
g++ -g -DDEBUG -c cookie.cpp
g++ -g -DDEBUG mainProg.o cookie.o -o playChomp

$ ./playChomp 
Hello World!
```

The error you are getting suggests the file is not there (in the directory where you are executing make).  Ensure that you are calling make from the directory where those files exist, and triple check the spelling (i.e. make sure you have `cookie.h`, not `Cookie.h`, etc.)

Comment: yes i have done all that. i triple checked everything. when i exacute the command "make" i get no errors and everything compiles correctly . but when i execute the ./playChomp it opens up fine but it wont work correctly .

Comment: @B-rad glad to hear the issue you described in your question has been resolved. Consider up voting and/or accepting one of the answers. It sounds like you are having a new problem with your program not working properly. If you cannot figure out that issue feel free to post a new question with details about that problem including the code that is giving you problems and a description of how the results are different from what you expect.